# gitでコードを書くのとvscodeで書くのはgitの方がいいですか？

Tags: git, vscode, エディタ

gitとvscodeの違いというか、vscodeで編集したものをgitに反映させる事ってできますか？
できるとしたら、どんなやり方あるんですかね？

分かる方、どうかよろしくお願いします。m(_ _)m

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問についてなのですが、実は VS Code はエディタ、Git はバージョン管理システムであり、通常比較されるようなものではありません。このため質問内容が伝わりづらくなっています。質問を [edit] して、より具体的に、VS Code と Git でそれぞれどんなことをなさりたいのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、知りたい内容は GitHub に関係がありますか？

Comment: タイトルに「gitでコードを書く」とありますが、gitはエディタではありませんのでコードを書くことはできません。何か盛大な勘違いがあるように思われます。

Comment: [「vs code git 設定」](https://www.google.com/search?q=vs+code+git+%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)でWeb検索をかけると[VSCodeでGit・GitHubを使う方法を解説する【初心者向き】](https://miya-system-works.com/blog/detail/vscode-github/)などの基本的な事項の解説サイトが出てきます。ご質問を具体的な内容に書きなおしていただくと、リンクの紹介よりも懸案に即した回答を得やすくなります。例えばVS Codeの機能でローカルリポジトリのブランチを作りたいのでしょうか。`GitHub`連携の設定でエラーが出るのでしょうか。ターミナルでコマンドを打ち込まずに`git`連携をしたいのでしょうか。そもそも`git`は便利らしいと聞いたけど意味が良く分からないのでしょうか。ぜひ前提知識と困っていることを追記なさってください。

Answer (score 1):

残念ながら、Gitってのはコードを書くものではありません。

> vscodeで編集したものをgitに反映させる事ってできますか？

できます。
この解答欄でGitの使い方の解説を行うというのはムリがありますので、まずは、
Git 使い方、などで検索してみましょう。
使い方の解説が出てきます
その上で疑問があれば聞いていただけるとよろしいかと