# gitでファイルの更新履歴を作るには？

Tags: git

例えば、cドライブの `/Usres/yuu/mysrc` の中の index.html というファイルの更新履歴を作れるようにするにはどうしたらいいですか？

分かる方、どうかよろしくお願いします。m(_ _)m

Comment: まずはチュートリアル等に目を通すことをお勧めします。 https://backlog.com/ja/git-tutorial/

Comment: 貴方がどの程度の知識を持っていて現在どのような状況にあるのか(例えばインストールは済んでいるのか/連携させる開発環境(エディタなのかIDEなのか)は何か/どんな書籍や記事を読んで理解しているのか)などの情報が無いので回答者が推測する範囲が多すぎて的確な回答が難しいように見えます。書かれた内容からすると、gitがどんな単位(個々のファイルというよりもあるディレクトリ以下のツリー全体)で対象を処理しているかの理解が出来ていない感じですが。

Comment: こんな記事 [gitのinit 〜 git commit までの流れ](https://qiita.com/tomsyoya/items/e11949bcc29d8cce035b) が参考になるはずですが、この内容が分からないのなら、そのわからない点を追記してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

gitのコマンドで更新履歴を見るならば、[`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)コマンドで表示できます。(`-p`オプションでファイルを指定します)

```
cd C:\Usres\yuu\mysrc
git log -p .\index.html
```

[以前のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/90858/9820)でVS Codeを使われているようでしたので、VS Code上でコマンドではなくグラフィカルに履歴を表示したいという意図であれば、基本機能ではできません。
[Git Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph)などの拡張機能をインストールする必要があります。
参考資料: [VSCode で Git のコミット履歴をわかりやすく時系列に木構造で見る方法](https://webgroove.work/vscode-install-git-graph/)

そもそもGitの`pull`や`init`など、「更新履歴を作れるようにする」操作が分からないのであれば、この質問や前回の質問のコメントを参考になさってください。